# Creating a function that changes the data types of columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4, create-function

UPDATED

I've written the following function and it is created successfully. But when I go to call it, an error pops up. I'm just learning how to use functions in Postgres, and I am confused here.

```
create function change_data_type()
returns void
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare


begin
    alter table summary_table
    alter column average_cost set data type decimal (3,2),
    alter column average_total set data type decimal(6,2);
    
return;
end;
$$;
```

The error message is as follows;

> ERROR:  column "decimal" does not exist
> LINE 1: decimal
> ^
> QUERY:  decimal
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function change_data_type() line 10 at RETURN
> SQL state: 42703

I've tried changing the return value to the specific column names, but it also returns an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: And the error message is classified information? You could add it to your question since it's plain text. And why do you create a function for something that you execute only once? `returns decimal` and `return 'success'` will not work, `success` is not a decimal, but text

Comment: You declare `returns decimal` yet you actually `return 'success';`, which is text. FYI, from here [Alter Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html): *All the forms of ALTER TABLE that act on a single table, except RENAME, SET SCHEMA, ATTACH PARTITION, and DETACH PARTITION can be combined into a list of multiple alterations to be applied together.*. You don't need to do `ALTER TABLE ...` twice.

Comment: 1) Your change is not going to work, you can't return a type you have to return a value of the type. 2) In this case you don't need to return anything, so you should declare `returns void`. 3) This does not need to be in a function, just run it as a compound statement. 4) You need to spend time reading [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

Comment: Just don't use a function for this, you don't change the data type of a table more then once. Especially not when you're not yet familiar with writing functions.

Comment: I went ahead and changed both return statements, and it worked. It definitely could be, but for sake of trying to make a function I wanted to try. Like you suggested returns void, and then I left the return statement at the end blank, so it only reads return; @AdrianKlaver

Comment: When you use `returns void` a `return` is not necessary unless you want to return(leave) the function early based on some condition test. All this is spelled out in the `plpgsql` doc link I posted. Spending time reading the information there will answer a lot of questions.